# Running a by ref selection sort function in C++ more than once

Tags: c++, recursion, pass-by-reference, static-variables, selection-sort

My assignment is to create a recursive selection sort function in C++. It runs as intended the on the first call in main, but selecting Selection Sort in the while loop main menu a second time produces some strange results. Im not sure if its an issue with passing by reference, the static variable in selectionSort(), or something else entirely.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

//Function Prototypes
void selectionSort(array<int, 10> &arrayRef, size_t size); //Passes a size 10 int array by ref
void rollDice(unsigned int numRolls); //Parameter is number of times the two die should roll

int main()
{
    int usrIn;

    cout << "Welcome to Program Assignment 2!";

    while (true) //Main Menu Loop
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        cout << "\n\n1) Selection Sort\n2)Roll Dice Simulation\n3)End The Program\nSelect an Option."
            << endl;

        cin >> usrIn;

        if (usrIn == 1)
        {
            cout << "Maximum value for array variables to be sorted: " << endl;
            cin >> usrIn; //Retrieves the user input max int value for the array's number generator
            array<int, 10> arrayToSort; //Initializes the test array of size 10

            for (int &val : arrayToSort) //Generates values for the array
                val = rand() % usrIn + 1;

            cout << "\nbefore sort:\n";
            for (int val : arrayToSort) //Displays numbers before the array is sorted
                cout << val << " ";

            selectionSort(arrayToSort, 10); //Sorts the array in numerical order

            cout << "\nafter sort:\n";
            for (int val : arrayToSort) //Displays numbers after the array is sorted
                cout << val << " ";

        }
    }


    return 0;
}

void selectionSort(array<int, 10> &arrayRef, size_t size)
{
    static int counter = 0;

    if (size <= 1)
        return;

    for (int i = counter; i < arrayRef.size(); i++)
    {
        if (arrayRef[i] < arrayRef[counter])
        {
            swap(arrayRef[i], arrayRef[counter]);
        }
    }

    counter++;
    selectionSort(arrayRef, size - 1);
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but you only need to call `srand` *once*.

Comment: And it might definitely have something to do with the static variable in the `selectionSort` function. Try to reset it after sorting.

Comment: remove "static" and initialize `counter` with this `counter = 10 - size;`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is rather unwieldy, so I won't attempt to refactor it. Instead, consider using this generic and recursive implementation of selection sort (uses C++11 default function template parameters)

```
template<class ForwardIterator, class Compare = std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::value_type>>
void selection_sort(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, Compare cmp = Compare{})
{
        if (first == last) return;
        auto const selection = std::min_element(first, last, cmp);
        std::iter_swap(selection, first);
        selection_sort(++first, last, cmp);
}
```

The key here is to increment the `first` iterator (pointer to the first array element in your program), not to decrement the `last` iterator (size in your program).

Of course, this has a tail recursion that can easily be taken out by an outer loop giving back the usual iterative implementation.